# ImportError: No module named 'users'

Tags: python, django

When I run `python /manage.py runserver` , it generates the following error.

```
ImportError: No module named 'users'
```

I was thinking about this error, maybe I had a mistake about app setting.

**$tree**

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── functional_test.py
├── requirement
│   ├── development.txt
│   └── production.txt
├── users
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── wef
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    └── wef
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
        │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
        │   └── urls.cpython-35.pyc
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

I think it is not a problem.

2nd, maybe I don't insert `'users'` in `settings.py`

**In settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_extensions',

    'users',
]
```

I have to double check about these situations.

Here's my code:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from users.views import JoinUsView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', user, name='home'),
]
```

**users/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def user(request):
    return HttpResponse("hello world")
```

Comment: Where does the `ImportError` happen? Can you edit your question with the full traceback?

Comment: From what I can tell, your `users` directory needs to be inside the first `wef` directory (the same level as manage.py)

Comment: @ShangWang umm... I solved my mistake .... but I 'm so glad about your kind thank you!

Comment: @Sayse oh..... hahaha... Thank you Sayse!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the import error because the `users` directory is not on the Python path. The easiest solution is to move the `users` directory into the project `wef` directory (the one that contains `manage.py`).

```
└── wef
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── users
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    ...
    └── wef
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── __pycache__
        │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
        │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
        │   └── urls.cpython-35.pyc
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

This will work because `./manage.py` adds the project directory to the Python path. If the `users` directory is outside of the project directory, then you will have to modify the python path yourself.