# Quora Python library not installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, python-module, quora

I am using macOS 10.13.1 (which is the latest version at this moment) on a MacBook Pro 13" Early 2015, and am trying to install the "quora" library for python 3.6.1. I am trying to install it by typing this into the terminal:

```
pip install quora
```

When I do so, it says it is already installed. Then when I type into the python IDLE IDE:

```
import quora
```

As a single line program, it says that no module named quora is found, yet when my terminal specifically says it has already been installed. 
Any information about how I can fix this will greatly be appreciated. Thank-you.

Edit #1:
When I input in terminal:

```
pip3 install quora
```

And I run the import in IDLE, it gives this error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/Hussein/Downloads/quora_install.py", line 1, in 
    import quora
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/quora/**init**.py", line 8, in 
    from user import User, Activity
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user'

Edit #2:
Up until this point I have been using the IDE for Python 3.6. I tried to run the import in Python 2.7, which is the default for the Mac, and works fine. But I do not know if there are functions that I need that may have been added to Python after the 2.7 release. I still wish to continue trying to get it work for v3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple Python versions on your machine? Try pip3 install quora?

Comment: Hello Bondrak, I will update the question to show what the results of this was

Comment: possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977723/python-packages-are-imported-on-terminal-but-not-on-idle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617396/import-urllib3-works-in-terminal-but-not-on-idle

Comment: Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507856/importerror-no-module-named-users